# why is the address of a c++ function always True?

Tags: c++, gcc, function-pointers

well why would,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int afunction () {return 0;};

int anotherfunction () {return 0;};

int main ()
{
    cout << &afunction << endl;
}
```

give this,

`1`

1. why is every functions address true?
2. and how then can a function pointer work if all functions share (so it seems) the same addresss?

Comment: I suspect the stream operator to interpet it wrong. Try (void*)&afunction, perhaps with a hex manipulator before it.

Comment: `(void*)&afunction` Works! you dont need the manipulator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function address isn't "true".  There is no overload for an ostream that accepts an arbitrary function pointer.  But there is one for a boolean, and function pointers are implicitly convertable to bool.  So the compiler converts `afunction` from whatever its value actually is to `true` or `false`.  Since you can't have a function at address `0`, the value printed is always `true`, which `cout` displays as `1`.

This illustrates why implicit conversions are usually frowned upon.  If the conversion to `bool` were explicit, you would have had a compile error instead of silently doing the wrong thing.

Comment: +1, same as I said but quicker. "There is no overload for an ostream that accepts a function pointer". At least, there isn't one that accepts *every* function pointer. There are three (templates) that accept particular kinds of function pointer, for stream manipulators, but they don't print the address anyway.

Comment: I thought the `type` of all pointers was numeric. I would ask why they aren't but I get that's a whole other SO question. thanks @Steve jessop and @Dennis Zickefoose.

Comment: @code shogan: function pointers and object pointers aren't the same thing (because functions aren't objects). There's an `operator<<` for `void*`, but not for `int(*)(void)`.

Comment: @Steve my first mistake was assuming everything is an object since C++ was OO. kind of like the language *eating it's own dogfood" e.g. In Python everything is an object.

Answer (score 3):

The function pointer type is not supported by `std::ostream` out of the box. Your pointers are converted to only possible compatible type - `bool` - and verything that is not zero is `true` thanks to backward compatibility to C.

Answer (score 2):

There's no overload of `operator<<` for function pointers (except stream manipulators), but there is one for `bool`, so the function pointer is converted to that type before display.

The addresses aren't equal, but they're both non-null, and hence they both covert to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overloaded function: `operator<<(ostream&, int(*)())`, so your function pointer is converted into the only type that works, `bool`. Then `operator<<(ostream&, bool)` is printing the converted value: 1.

You may be able to print the function address like so:

```
cout << (void*)&afunction << endl;
```

Comment: yeah Christian Rau pointed that out. Maybe it's my background in Python, but I assumed pointers share a type (aka. inheritance)... but now I'm thinking in C++ things like pointers *are* the type.

Comment: @code - Pointers to objects *sort of* share an inheritance. Any pointer to an object can be converted to `void*`. Pointers to functions are not convertible to `void*`.

Comment: @Rob aha now i get how the above example works: we aren't converting pointers but actually just *creating* a void pointer instead. It all finally makes sense. +1

Comment: @code note that `(void&)&func` is a gcc extension. The C++ standard makes no guarantee that this will work.

Comment: Err, I meant "`(void*)&func` is a gcc extension"

Comment: @Rob if it's not part of the standard then I guess that means that in everyday programming it's not something you would need to do... but the extension is just there for those who for some reason want it. right?

Answer (score 0):

All addresses in C++ are non-zero, because zero is the NULL pointer and is a reserved value. Any non-zero value is considered true.

Comment: Doesn't touch on why the value is always 1 (rather than 0x400110 or something).

Comment: @cHao, I didn't think I needed to explain that; judging by the question title, I assumed the asker knew that True was equal to 1.

Comment: Going just by the title, you're right.  Part 2 of the actual question, though, indicates that the expected almost certainly isn't `true` or 1, but the function's address.  The confusion isn't about the value of a boolean, so much as it's about function pointers mysteriously becoming bools in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be an overload  for function pointers for the iostream << operator, as there are an infinite number of possible function pointer types. So the function pointer gets a conversion applied, in this case to bool. Try:

```
cout << (void *) afunction << endl;
```

Which will give you the address in hex - for me the result was:

```
0x401344
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you check `anotherfunction()` as well?

Anyway, C++ pointer addresses, like C pointer addresses, are usually virtual on most platforms and don't correspond directly to memory locations. Hence the value may be very small or unusual.

Also, they will always be true, as `0` is `NULL`, an invalid pointer, and anything that is over 0 is true

Comment: Doesn't touch on why the value is always 1 (rather than 0x400110 or something).