# rand()/RAND_MAX function prints 1 every time

Tags: c++, random

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


void seedRandom()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
}

double nextRandom()
{
  seedRandom();
  double ran;
  ran = ( (double) rand()) / RAND_MAX;
  cout << ran;
  return ran;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<nextRandom;
}
```

Why does this print 1 every time and not a random number between 0 and 1? I looked everywhere but it does not seem to work. This is due at midnight. Also, this is only an excerpt from a long code.

Comment: It's a bad idea to div by RAND_MAX for customizing rand() range. Why don't you use std::mt19937, std::random_device and std::uniform_real_distribution?

Comment: On top of the answer get `seedRandom();` out of `nextRandom`. Instead call `seedRandom()` 1 time  in main.

Comment: do not put `srand` inside a function, it's supposed to be called only once at startup [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714)

Answer (score 4):

```
cout<<nextRandom;
```

This does not call your `nextRandom` function. The right argument to `<<` is a pointer to the function, not the result of calling it. In this context, if I'm not mistaken, the pointer value is implicitly converted to `bool`, yielding `true` (1) if the pointer is not null -- which it never will be.

Add empty parentheses to call the function.

Comment: [Why std::cout << main << std::endl prints 1? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28660352/995714), [Why pointer to function is equal to 1? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53129402/995714), [why is the address of a c++ function always True?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6022881/995714)

Answer (score 4):

I think there are several problems with your codes

- In main function, you should use `nextRandom()` as a function call instead of print function itself.
- You should `seedRandom` once only at the beginning instead of run it every time, because `time` function return seconds, so if you call `nextRandom()` multiple times inside a second, you might get the same random number.
- After C++11, you probably should consider use `<random>` library in C++ to generate random number with the range.

Here is the simple example as reference

```
double nextRandom()
{
  thread_local std::random_device rd;
  thread_local std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_real_distribution <> dist(0.0, 1.0);
  return dist(gen);
}
```